# civicrm 5.54.0 status page and menus not loading after upgrade

Tags: dashboard, angular

After upgrading my CIVICRM is not working anymore. Menu's are not available and Dashlets are empty. There seems to be an AngularJS issue. The file https://www.instituutvlaamsevolkskunst.be/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/dc.min.js.map is indeed not present. Same for this location https://www.instituutvlaamsevolkskunst.be/dc.min.js.map

[ While copying I notice the double forward slash before sites https://www.instituutvlaamsevolkskunst.be//sites - I modified this and it does not make a difference as the files are not present anyway]

Hope someone can point me in the right direction to fix this issue ...

Thanks
[image: Console output]

Comment: The first error (interest-cohort' went away after adding this line in settings.php  $settings['block_interest_cohort'] = FALSE;

Comment: Meanwhile the angular error was cleared too, but this one still remains:
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://www.instituutvlaamsevolkskunst.be/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/dc.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

I suppose this one is preventing me from opening the status page /#/a and creating mailings ...

Answer (score 0):

Have are you using Drupal 8/9/10?  If so try

```
composer civicrm:publish
```

from command line

Comment: I was able to run the suggested command but it did not change the behavior.
Drupal version is 9.5.1, CiviCRM 5.57.0, PHP 7.4.33 (needs to be updated - could this be the origin of the problem?)